# Checking if RAM is functional

Tags: hardware

I'm trying to revive an old travelMate 518tx and I'm currently in the process of searching for bottlenecks. I want to check if the RAM sticks are still functional or not, but they're both very old, and I'm unsure how I can test them.

Is there a way to either insert them into my computer or to see if they work?

Picture of the RAM sticks (pencil for scale):

[image]

Comment: «pencil for scale):» that begs the question of how long is the pencil?

Comment: @JDługosz 5-7 cm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those look like 144-pin [SO-DIMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO-DIMM) memory modules.  It's a very old memory technology.  If the computer you pulled them from isn't working, your best bet is to find a known-working laptop of about the same age that takes that type of memory, install the RAM sticks one at a time, and run [MemTest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) from a boot CD or floppy to check the memory.

Comment: @StephenKitt Memory technology ages quickly. That's why you (probably!) own a >1TiB drive, for example.

Comment: @Bálint I misread the Wikipedia article, the [JEDEC standard](http://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/docs/module-456) does indeed date back to 1999. SO-DIMM refers to the physical format; they use SDRAM.

Comment: @Bálint um? That's like pointing to a loaf of bread and saying "that's not a loaf, it's bread." What you have is SDRAM (post-EDO, pre-DDR), in SO-DIMM format.

Comment: _"It's a very old memory technology"_ ...Now _I_ feel old. My notebook still runs on these... (: